# Read default value of Material-UI toggle into State

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui

My Toggle switch looks like this:

```
class MyComponent extends Component
   {ton of code} 

<Toggle
   label={Click to enable Legacy deal}
   defaultToggled={false}
   labelPosition="right"
   {... styles stuff...}
   onToggle={handleLegacyToggle}
/>
```

How can I get the `defaultToggled=false` into my state when the page loads? I need the state to contain false even if the user does not interact with the toggle.

My workaround is to call `handleLegacyToggle` in `componentWillMount` and in my reducer have an if statement like this:

```
    case SET_LEGACY_FLAG:
      if(action.value) {
// if toggle has been toggled there will be a payload with action.value, so use the value send with the action else set to false
    return Object.assign({}, state, {'isLegacy': action.value});
    } else {
    return Object.assign({}, state, {'isLegacy': false});
    }
```

But this feels like a hack and I'm wondering if there is a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are doing things a bit opposite from the way they are supposed to be done.

Your state should never be updated from "defaultToggled={false}". However, your Toggle component should get the default false state from parents state.

In your parent component add:

```
this.state = { isToggled: false }
```

And than in your component:

```
<Toggle
   label={Click to enable Legacy deal}
   defaultToggled={this.state.isToggled}
   labelPosition="right"
   {... styles stuff...}
   onToggle={handleLegacyToggle}
/>
```

In case I didn't understood exactly what you need, please explain where and I will try to help as much as I can.

Comment: this worked - I was thinking that setting this.state in the parent component would alter the global state object(this is all in state.dealData)  but I guess it's the mapStateToProps that constrains this component to that section of State

Comment: @Vidro3 I am glad that I helped! :) Feel free to ask more. ;)